# How to implement ssl on website in shared hosting?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

i have developed website & i want to implement ssl in that but My domain is in shared hosting so i have no idea to how to set ssl.
My website is developed in.net
please any one help me out.

Comment: Your hosting provider has the answer

Comment: Hosting provider is godaddy.com

Comment: What I meant: they have to do it for you. You'll probably have to pay for it, too.

Comment: Ok thanks. i will contact them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would depend entirely upon your host.

You would be better off filing a support ticket with them and asking if they offer SSL. SSL requires a fixed IP, which some hosts can still do even with shared hosting.

It won't be free though.

Comment: +1. Basically ask your host. YOU can do NOTHING - unless the host is a total idiot and has not secured the machine, in which case you dont want to be there. SSDL adding is an admin level config change, so it has to go through your host. Ask their support - likely you need a different plan.